# Force system overlay in Landscape and activity in Portrait

Tags: android, orientation

I have an Activity *A* forced showing in **Portrait** mode and a system overlay UI *B* forced showing in **Landscape** mode. The overlay *B* is added on runtime when Activity *A* is shown. The problem is that when the overlay is added, the device rotate to landscape, causing the application to "crash" via a WindowLeaked exception.

The screen orientation for the system overlay *B* is set with:

```
params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
```

And the screen orientation for the Activity is set via the manifest with:

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

And with a custom WindowOrientationListener, the activity is put to 0 degree (portrait) to do custom rotation on the views.

How can we put the activity in portrait and the system overlay in landscape **at the same time**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call overlay.setRotation(90) in oncreate of Activity A.